# Is it possible to exclude a certain string from .length in a String[]?

Tags: java

I'm working on a command-based modification for Minecraft in which you are allowed to use flags (-[a-z]) to specify certain values. However, I'm slightly confused on how I should go about parsing regular arguments. Here's an example of a command: `/tp fist -h`. Of course, it's relatively simple to what string[0] equals, but if I were to try `/tp -h fist`, I'm afraid I would confuse the modification and it would throw an exception.

So, my question is: is it possible to create a String[ ] which removes a specific type of string from an existing list so I can do `if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("text")` and it would do the same thing for `/command text [text-to-remove]` as if I did `/command [text-to-remove] text`?

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,

afistofirony

PS: I know I can use a for loop to check each individual argument, but normally the variables will change for each execution (since they are usually used to specify players that don't all share a name).

Comment: Could you stand to use an external library? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. You will have to either recreate a subset array of the original or keep track of the ignored indexes.

The long answer is that you could create your own collection that does this implicit filtering.

In a FP language like scala filtering a collection is much easier. Java you will have to usually loop through the collection.